# Prove a limit of a sequence by definition

Tags: calculus

I need to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (na^n)=0$ , $|a|<1$ using the epsilon-M definition.

---

I have tried the following method: Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Suppose that $a\neq 0$. Then $|n a^n-0|=n|a^n|=|a|^{\log_{|a|}(n)}|a^n|=|a|^{n+\log_{|a|}(n)}$. Since $\log_{|a|}(n)$ is non-positive and it decreases slower than n grows, and $|a|<1, a\neq 0$, from some $M \in \Bbb N$ that depends on the $\epsilon$ we choose, we obtain $|a|^{n+\log_{|a|}(n)}<\epsilon$.

If $a=0$, then $|na^n|=0<\epsilon$.

Is my proof correct? If not, could you please show the existence of the limit above using the epsilon-M definition?

Comment: You need exact prove, that for given $\varepsilon$ exists $M$, s.t. for $n>M$ holds inequality - not words such "slower".

Comment: I also felt so, but the problem is that I don't know how to prove it formally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using inequalities
$na^n=\frac{n}{\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^n} = \frac{n}{b^n}=\frac{n}{[1+(b-1)]^n}<\frac{n}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}(b-1)^2}=\frac{2}{(n-1)(b-1)^2}$, for given $\varepsilon >0$, we find $M$ s.t. $\frac{2}{(n-1)(b-1)^2} < \varepsilon$ for $n>M$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very, very much!!!

Comment: Glad to be of useful. Since you are a new here, let me say, that you can choose this answer, if you think it answers your question.